# Defining arithmetic operations in a class

Tags: c#, class, math, methods

I'm creating a library dll in c# with my own classes. But, for arithmetic operations (+, -, *, /, ...) I've created methods like .Add (c1, c2) where c1 and c2 are objects of my class.

This method is great, but I'd prefer to be able to say: c3 = c1 + c2; and since I've already written my Add function, Multiply function, Divide function etc etc for my classes I'd like to define that:

c1 = c2 + c3   is the same that: c1 = MyClass.Add (c2, c3);

So I would reuse my code, if it's possible. I'm sure there is documentation and information about all of this in the web, but I can't find it, anything I search, Google looks to misunderstand my question.

How can I define basic arithmetic operations for objects of my classes?

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for [operator overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tk49fh2.aspx).You need to overload + operator to tell the compiler how to perform an addition between two objects.Then you will be able to add two objects like you add two integer.

Here is an example of `+` operator overloading from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx)

```
public static Complex operator +(Complex c1, Complex c2) 
{
   return new Complex(c1.real + c2.real, c1.imaginary + c2.imaginary);
}
```

Comment: Or since you already have this code in your static `.Add` method that you mentioned, you could just call that (assuming you still want to keep it): `return Complex.Add(c1, c2);`